# finish score activity to return back to surfaceview

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, surfaceview

i use surfaceview for my game.
When the game is complete it'll automatically start other activity (score activity) by this intent :

```
mContext = getContext();
Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, ScoreScreen.class);
mContext.startActivity(intent);
```

it works fine, but has one problem when i want to close that score activity then back to surfaceview ("Try again" button).

i use this code to finish score activity:

```
tryagain.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });
```

but it don't want back to surfaceview

Help me..

sorry for my bad english

this my SurfaceviewScreen :

```
    public class SurfaceScreen extends Activity {
    OurView v;
    int level =1, lives = 3, score=0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        v = new OurView(this);
        v.setKeepScreenOn(true);
        setContentView(v);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        v.pause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        v.resume();
    }

    public class OurView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {
        Thread t = null;
        SurfaceHolder holder;
        boolean isItOK = false;
        boolean spriteLoaded = false;
        private Context mContext;

        Paint paint = new Paint();

        public OurView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            this.mContext = context;
            mContext = getContext();
            holder = getHolder();
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (isItOK) {
                if (!holder.getSurface().isValid()) {
                    continue;
                }
                update();
                Canvas c = holder.lockCanvas();
                onDraw(c);
                holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(20);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        public void pause() {
            isItOK = false;
            while (true) {
                try {
                    t.join();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
            }
            t = null;
        }

        public void resume() {
            isItOK = true;
            t = new Thread(this);
            t.start();
        }

        protected void update(){
            if(lives<1){
                    Intent i = new Intent(mContext, gameover.class);
                    i.putExtra("msg", "LOSE");
                    mContext.startActivity(i);
            }
            //updating
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
                //drawing
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my ScoreScreen code :

```
    public class ScoreScreen extends Activity{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.scorescreen);

        TextView txtResult = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.scorescreen_result);
        Button tryagain = (Button)findViewById(R.id.scorescreen_tryagain);
        Intent i = this.getIntent();
        txtResult.setText(i.getStringExtra("msg"));

        tryagain.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: this code seems to correct. please add your code to understand the problem

Comment: @Jatin what are you on about?

Comment: about your surfaceview screen

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can uderstand your question you should try

```
ScoreActivity.this.finish();
```